# Combining query with date histogram

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to calculate number of documents from last hour and aggregate them in 5 minute buckets.
This is my query:

```
    GET logs-tsi-2019.05/tsi-json-log/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": "now-1h",
                  "lt": "now"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term" : {
                "application" : "sso"
              }
            },
            {
              "query_string": {
                "default_field": "*",
                "query": "grant_type=refresh_token",
                "analyze_wildcard": true
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

How to combine this query with date_histogram aggregation?

regards,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start! You can do it like this:

```
GET logs-tsi-2019.05/tsi-json-log/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "now-1h",
              "lt": "now"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term" : {
            "application" : "sso"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "*",
            "query": "grant_type=refresh_token",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "5min": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "@timestamp",
        "interval": "5m"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Do you know if it's possible to return just the aggregations? I get over 100 results and don't care about details - just aggregations are important for me.

Comment: Ok - I got it - in the beginning one have to specify   "size": 0,